# AMS Euler, but slightly heavier using METAFONT?

Tags: fonts, metafont, math-fonts, euler

I'm using a commercial body text font and I'd like to use a math font that matches it well. AMS Euler (from the `eulervm` package) matches its style nicely, but is slightly too light. I know AMS Euler was originally digitized in METAFONT, and METAFONT supports parametrization - for example, the original Computer Modern METAFONT had a "blacker" parameter to adjust font weight. However, I don't know:

1. Did the Euler METAFONT also have an adjustable "blackness" parameter?
2. How can I get my hands on the Euler METAFONT sources?

There's also the problem of, once I've got my hands on the Euler METAFONT, whether I can turn it into an outline font. But I know of a few tools that claim to do that, most recently mf2outline (https://github.com/linusromer/mf2outline). So I'm most interested in the above questions.

Comment: the metafont sources are not compatible with the current (improved) type1 version and so have been removed from the distribuation, see the amsfonts readme http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/amsfonts/README. You should look in the historic texlive archive (somewhere before 2008 could work) http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/systems/texlive/

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately, I think you're out of luck. To the best of my knowledge, AMS Euler was not a “true” metafont; it just happened to use METAFONT. See the quotes collected in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332429/translation-of-typefaces-into-metafont-in-the-case-of-ams-euler-and-others). So you may not be able to vary `blacker`.