# mktexmf cannot find cmathbb fonts (Linux)

Tags: fonts, blackboard

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cmathbb}

\begin{document}
    \[ \mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R} \subset
    \mathbb{C} \subset \mathbb{H} \subset \mathbb{O}
    \]
\end{document}
```

I want to use the blackboard letters which match the Computer Modern font from the [`cmathbb`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cmathbb) font package. The above code (from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656644/128462)) does not compile and I get the following errors in the output.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./a.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-08-30>
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cmathbb/cmathbb.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./a.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cmathbb/ucmath.fd)
kpathsea: Running mktextfm Cmathbb-Regular-tlf-t1
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source abbreviation C for Cmathbb-Regular-tlf-t1.
/usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Need to update /usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/map/fontname/special.map?
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input Cmathbb-Regular-tlf-t1
This is METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf Cmathbb-Regular-tlf-t1
! I can't find file `Cmathbb-Regular-tlf-t1'.
<*> ...; nonstopmode; input Cmathbb-Regular-tlf-t1

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...; nonstopmode; input Cmathbb-Regular-tlf-t1

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: Cmathbb-Regular-tlf-t1.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input Cmathbb-Regular-tlf-t1' failed to make Cmathbb-Regular-tlf-t1.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font U/cmath/m/n/10=Cmathbb-Regular-tlf-t1 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TF
M) file not found.
<to be read again> 
relax 
l.5     \[ \mathbb{N}
\subset \mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R} ...
```

Edit: Upon reading the comments, it seems that this is a bug in the package, for Linux. The code compiles without any problems on Windows; I don't know about MacOS.

Comment: It works on my computer. Maybe your TeX Live is damaged.

Comment: @Clara you are on Windows I guess?

Comment: The files inconsistently reference `\cmathbb-...` and `Cmathbb-...` so will not work on a case sensitive file system. I looked yesterday but was travelling, best to raise with the maintainers

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Huh. I never testedit  on Linux.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I am on Windows 10, TeX Live 2022.

Comment: @Clara yes it's a file system dependent bug in the package/font distribution

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It’s copied from [this answer.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656644/61644)

Comment: I ran into the same on macOS, so I asked the author.

Comment: @HironobuYAMASHITA I had mailed the author a few months back. I had received a reply that he will look into it.