# Why Does CTAN not Distribute European Modern?

Tags: fonts, ctan, copyright

In a comment to [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656644/61644), @Οurous pointed me to an important find I had missed.  The European Modern fonts by Y&Y were originally a commercial add-on for Y&Y TeX, and are missing from the yandytex packages on CTAN.  They are superior in some ways to the `cm-super` fonts that are currently the default for LaTeX with the Cork encoding, and are closely related to the “Blue Sky” fonts (from Y&Y in the ’90s) that are the default when using the original OT1 encoding.  However, the European Modern files are not available from CTAN, or in any distribution I am aware of.

Of note, [the support files to use European Modern are on CTAN as the `psnfssx-em` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/psnfssx-em), last updated in 2001.  These do not distribute the fonts themselves, but only provide support files if you have copies of the fonts Y&Y used to sell in the 1990s.

However, [a version of the fonts originally shipped on four diskettes](https://github.com/clerkma/yytex/tree/master/fonts/em) was donated to TUG and is available freely for download on GitHub, with a copyright statement that says “Copyright 2007 TeX Users Group,” [and that](https://github.com/clerkma/yytex/tree/master/fonts)  **ETA:** The original release was [on Google Code](https://code.google.com/archive/p/yytex/), and the GitHub link is to a mirror.

> Blue Sky, Y&Y, and the AMS released the AMS and Computer Modern fonts
> long ago under free software terms.  To whatever extent that Y&Y had any
> remaining proprietary improvements in the fonts as they are included
> here, they have been assigned to TUG, and TUG hereby releases them as
> free software, under the one-sentence all-permissive license (to avoid
> license compatibility problems):
>
> You may freely use, modify and/or distribute the material here.
>
> Any complete fonts given here which have not previously been released
> (I'm not sure if there are any) are also hereby released under that
> all-permissive license.

Is there any reason TUG could not make the European Modern fonts, which they claimed to own in 2007, freely available today?  Is the situation that anyone could have bundled them into a package at any time since 2007, but no one ever did?

Comment: did you try to contact TUG and ask them?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, I’m not sure who to ask. David Carlisle is listed as the maintainer of `psnfssx-em`, and I know he reads this site.

Comment: you are asking about the actual fonts, and claim that TUG has the rights. David is not TUG. So go to the TUG website and find the contact address. That is not difficult.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Fair point. TUG’s answer is likely to be, “Yep, we released them, and anybody could’ve made a package at any time in the past fifteen years,” but I should ask.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Huh. I never realized they were in my hometown.

Comment: Am I?? wow, you learn something every day!

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I’ve also sent the e-mail, as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I heard back from Karl Berry on 8 October 2022.  According to him,

> FYI, nothing TeXnical that Y&Y had the rights to was held back from the
> donation. I.e., Y&Y gave us disk images of their development machine.
> (Thanks again to Blenda Horn for doing this.)

There is, that he knows of, nothing complicating the legal status of European Modern fonts and no reason they could not be turned into a package.