# How to customize chapter?

Tags: chapters, custom

[image]

I dont know how to custom the chapter like this. Can you help me please

Answer (score 4):

I really advise against scaling fonts with `\scalebox`. My suggestion would be:

1. [use a modern font encoding](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/664/why-should-i-use-usepackaget1fontenc)
2. use a full scalable font, [there are several options for Computer Modern](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/656626/comparison-of-vector-fonts-of-computer-modern-variants)
3. select the font size you want with `\fontsize...\selectfont`

Like this:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Include this package

% Customizing the chapter title format
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}
  {\fontsize{4cm}{4cm}\selectfont\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge} % Scale the chapter number (change size)

% Customizing the spacing before and after the chapter title
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{9} % remove me
\chapter{Polar Coordinates, Parametric Equations}

% Your chapter content goes here.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to **@John Smith** for the MWE --- **@Benjamín García**, *please* provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for your new questions.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Include this package

% Customizing the chapter title format
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries\centering}
  {\scalebox{3}{\thechapter}}{20pt}{\Huge} % Scale the chapter number (change size)

% Customizing the spacing before and after the chapter title
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Polar Coordinates, Parametric Equations}

% Your chapter content goes here.

\end{document}
```

Ouput:
[image]

`\setcounter{chapter}{9}` can be added before the first `\chapter` command to start the chapter numbering at `10`.
The formatting command within `\titleformat` does not print the chapter number anymore because the `{}` after `\huge\bfseries\centering` is empty. If you want to manually insert "`10`", you would put it in there.

Comment: Changed it, so the chapter is automatically numbered

Comment: sorry, but i cant create a table of contents if i use your code. how can it be fixed??

Comment: You need to compile it twice

Comment: Thank you very much, another question, is it possible to enlarge only the size of the chapter number?

Comment: {\scalebox{3}{\thechapter}}{20pt}{\Huge} % Scale the chapter number by changing the number in the scalebox

Comment: I've edited my answer

Comment: sorry but, and what specific place i have to put this?

Comment: I've edited the answer so it includes it now