Original font used to model MathTime Pro II Curly Script
I am attaching a montage showing the use of an old font by two different publishers.  I hope it is clear: I had to use jpeg due to size constraints.  The font is slightly different between the two (note the C and G in particular), but that is to be expected, I should think, in the days of manual typesetting.  I have labeled the letters I could find using Dr. Spivak's Curly Script from MathTime Pro II (including variants), which was clearly designed to imitate this font. Obviously, it varies somewhat from the original (I am not sure whether that is a T or a J although I lean toward T since it refers to a category of triangulable pairs) and this may well be because he may not have had the entire font available to model.  Before posting this question, I searched extensively on the web, so I know that I am not the only person who likes this font.  It obviously predates MathTime and computer typesetting in general.  Does anyone know what it is and where to get a proof sheet (or whatever they were called in those days) showing the entire font?  I am not even certain I have ever seen the lowercase outside of the MathTime rendition.  I would like to digitize this font as much like the original as possible.  It is bound to be public domain (1952 at least) and ought to be available.  I'll settle for a steer in the direction where I am likely to find the answer: I know it may require finding someone who was actually in the printing business back then.  If this was going to be easy, I would have found the answer on the web.

Alternatively, if anyone can find any more of the characters in this font in old textbooks and upload them here, perhaps the whole font--or enough to extrapolate the rest--can be assembled.

Sorry, but this question is IMHO off-topic here. A question about how to use a specific font in (La)TeX would be on-topic. But this question is more about which font it is or something like this. (Or is it how to digitize it or where to get examples of all glyphs? Doesn't matter, would be off-topic too.)

@cabohah Yes, well, unfortunately, I was unable to find a more fitting forum.  The last question that I posted which I thought was more font- than TeX-related to the SE in Graphic Design is still sitting dormant after many weeks.  Meanwhile, I received the answer to the same question in this forum almost immediately.  My experience in this forum is that a lot of people who are fluent in TeX and LaTeX know a thing or two about fonts also.

This question is similar to: How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@MS-SPO As I intimated, I did an extensive search before asking the question and that post was obviously one of the things that turned up.  I thoroughly exhausted all of the links on that page and the links that were subsidiary to no avail.  None of the tools listed identified the font.  I have since found the font in dozens of old texts by different publishers.  Someone, somewhere, must know what it is.  I grant you this was not the first place I thought to ask this question, but there does not appear to be a similar font-oriented forum in which to ask it.  Maybe we need one.

I suggest to EDIT your question and insert a few paragraphs, to make your monolithic block easier to digest. E.g. your search should stand out, and your question (1), of course ... // Also, aren't there similar enough fonts you could use?

There is at least this thread https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends?page=1&tab=modifieddesc#tab-top , and I think there are more, replication beautiful typography. Unless you know it, you may find a hint or person to dig deeper.

Imho, since the MathTime fonts are almost exclusively used in latex/tex, this should be considered on-topic. While there are other sites dealing with font design, the people who could answer this question are more likely to be found here rather than on ther sites.

Also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186512/did-knuth-actually-design-the-computer-modern-font is purely a font question, but it's still on-topic, with 46 upvotes!

@ApoorvPotnis Good point!  As it happens, I eventually found the rest of that font, although I had to dig through hundreds of old texts to do so.  But it was worth it!  And I designed a lowercase that matches (at least I think so).  Now, there is a similar-but-dissimilar-enough-to-warrant-reproducing font that I have only been able to find in two texts so far, so I may post a question about that if I don't have any luck finding more.

@MikePugh Can you please tell me the origins about the font? Can you please add a link to the font that you've created, if you've released it? Also, the font that you've created is not suited for Times, is it? As the necessary modifications to suit Times were made by the Spivak

I don't know how willing the publishers (Princeton press and Academic press) would be to help you, but you can ask some high-ranking person (if you know them personally) in those publishers. It is possible that they still have the old metal sorts.

@ApoorvPotnis I have no idea of the origins.  I just like the font.  It varies enough from script to be used alongside it if necessary and you can generally tell which glyph represents which letter (the same cannot be said or Fraktur, which should limit its use to Lie algebras, ideals, and whatever it has been used for up till now).

@MikePugh you can try asking barbara beeton in the chat room. she used to work for the AMS, and probably can point you in the right direction.

I will eventually release the font, but it is still in design phase and is part of a much larger package that I hope will encompass a lot of old fonts that I have been sad to see disappear.  And yes, I am designing it so that its metrics exactly match TeX Gyre Termes, which is based on Nimbus Roman 9 from Monotype.  At least in terms of cap-height and x-height.  Spivak narrowed some of these characters from the originals and I think the originals look better.
